# Making calculator with real image/images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I would like to make a calculator using real image or more of them in **html css** and **javascript**. Is there any suggestion on how to do that? Should I use something like image mapping or cut it in photoshop then connect it like a puzzle?

(The question is only about the interface. To be precise, the question is how to empower buttons and display)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use background-position property and use only one image.

```
background-position:left top;
background-position:center top;
background-position:right top;
```

and so on for each button/div.

Here's an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{ 
    background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg');
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
}

div#lt{
background-position: top left; 
}

div#ct{
background-position: top center; 
}

div#rt{
background-position: top right; 
}

div#lc{
background-position: center left; 
}

div#cc{
background-position: center center; 
}

div#rc{
background-position: center right; 
}

div#lb{
background-position:left bottom; 
}

div#cb{
background-position: center bottom; 
}

div#rb{
background-position: right bottom; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="lt"></div>
<div id="ct"></div>
<div id="rt"></div>
<br />
<div id="lc"></div>
<div id="cc"></div>
<div id="rc"></div>
<br />
<div id="lb"></div>
<div id="cb"></div>
<div id="rb"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best cu cut them in photoshop so you can bind javascript events on each image separately.

Otherwise you would have to compute x, y position of the click to know which button was clicked.

Better still is if you can style the buttons with only css. For a calculator it shouldn't be very hard, depending on the design.